# How to extract textbox & flowcharts from Word( doc,docx) files using Python?

Tags: python, automation, ms-word

I am preparing automation code to extract flow diagrams,shapes (non-image) along with text present inside them from word files(doc,docx).

I tried using  `rIds`(relationship ids) to identify them with python but failed. Can anyone suggest better solution?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [PyDocX](https://pydocx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library to convert the docx to html and then extract the images using the tags. The conversion is pretty good, you can give it a try

```
PyDocX.to_html(directory+'hey.docx')
```

Comment: I actually need to extract non-image shapes as mentioned in question, can  those be extracted from HTML ?

Comment: is it a specific format or a different format in all the docs?